# Mobile: Best practice for number of products in a listing?

Tags: mobile, lists, e-commerce, mobile-web

Is there a best practice approach on the number of products listed per page on mobile? For example, when a user browses a category is it better to have fewer products listed than one might have on desktop (to reduce scrolling)?

In my case, the products are displayed as thumbnails in a 2 column layout. The site is an ecommerce site and has a rather large catalogue of products.

I did find some similar topics on this, but not mobile specific. Any answers or links on this subject would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pages. Instead, [load more](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/) is more effective on small touchscreens, because it's easier to tap accurately and avoids page reloads.

As for how many you should load, that same study proposes **15 to 30 items**. Any more, and users start needing to scroll too far. Fewer, and users get annoyed that they have to keep tapping all the time. The study's images show that they used a 1-column approach, so if you have 2 columns, you can safely trend towards the higher end of that spectrum.